# Laravel File Privacy

Tags: php, laravel

I Have an application,users can register within application,and they can upload their own files.

My Question is, how Can I add privacy to the files in such way files can not be accessed without authentication and each user should access only their own file

Comment: Create a relationship between files and users, then only serve the files binary `response()->download('/path/to/file')` where `path/to/file` is a secure location on your filesystem. An example of serving files binary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145223/2797224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep all the files in folders not accessible by any user, so you prevent any url guesses.

Your code will be responsible to validate if the user owns the file. Once the user is cleared, you move the file a temporary file, that is accessible to the public:

```
Storage::copy('restricted_folder/file.jpg', 'public_folder/random_name.jpg');
```

Then you return a response that will force the user to download the file, and remove the temporary file after the request:

```
    return response()->download('public_folder/random_name.jpg','file.jpg')->deleteFileAfterSend();
```

Comment: Moving the file, then deleting it after the download will mean the file is lost forever after a single download. Probably not ideal. `return response()->download('restricted_folder/file.jpg')` will work just fine without all the moving and deleting and wailing and gnashing of teeth.

Comment: You are right, what I wanted was to copy the file, thank you. But I believe you won't be able to download a file from a restricted folder.

Comment: You can with `response()->download()`. It streams the file through Laravel.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here depends a bit on *how* secure this all needs to be.

You could generate a long, random filename for the file when it's uploaded. These are hard to guess - like a decently strong password - and in most cases will do the trick.

Laravel actually does this natively if you use the `store()` method:

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

If you need more security than that, you can store the uploaded files somewhere non-public. Then, add a route (like `download/{id}`), have that route check the user's permissions for the file in question, and serve the file to the browser if authorized:

```
return Storage::download('path/to/the.file');
```

`Storage::download` proxies the file through Laravel, so this works even on files not stored in the public folder.